# zsh: How to backspace through to the previous line?

Tags: zsh, backspace

When I type a multiline command like

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do
for> echo $i
for> done
1
2
3
```

and then recall the command with up-arrow, backspacing stops at the start of the last line (i.e. after erasing `done`). Is there a way to make the zsh line editor keep backspacing by jumping to the end of `echo $i` and erasing the previous line? I know I can use up-arrow, but I would like to just keep backspacing. Interestingly, this works for word-erase with Ctrl-W but not for backspace.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? What you describe as your desired behaviour works for me as is (gnome-terminal).

Comment: Do you have TERM=xterm set in your .zshrc?

Comment: I use `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: Backspace being restricted to a single line is normal behavior for `vi`-like editors. Are you using `vi` mode?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Yup, `bindkey -v`; with `bindkey -e` backspacing across lines works. Is there a way to have the behavior with -v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `bindkeys -v` all the keys are set to vi-like behavior, including the backspace key which is bound to `vi-backward-delete-char`. You can override specific keys afterward, like this:

```
bindkey '^h' backward-delete-char
```

or perhaps `^?` instead of `^h` - type Ctrl-V Backspace to get the right code.

Comment: You can use bindkey | grep delete to have a look at all the delete bindings beyond backspace as well.

Comment: `bindkey '^?' backward-delete-char` did it!